# Resharper 2017 custom rules setting

Tags: visual-studio-2017, rules, resharper-2017

I am working with Resharper 2018. My boss wants me to set some of the custom rules in Resharper tool. Now I would like to know is there any way to set such rules for moving a specific file to a specific folder.

For example, A class name with the suffix **“Service”** (e.g. AccountService) will be moved to the folder named “Services”. It means whenever I will create a class outside of the **Services** folder with the suffix **Service** there will be a suggestion from Resharper to move that file into the **Services** folder.

Another rule can be, creating a file with **.html** extension, outside of the **“Pages”** folder, there will always be suggestions from Resharper to move that files to the **Pages** folder.

I see that a built-in option available for moving files to the specific folder according to it's **Namespaces**.

Now I would like to extend this features for the above cases. Please let me know any suggestions or tutorials for doing that.

Thank you all.

Comment: Out of the box, this isn't possible, however, you can write a custom plugin for this. Here is some introduction to the topic: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/README.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Matthias